# Get Receiver Vehicle Position in BSM

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

How do I configure Veins to get the receiving vehicle's position (x and y) in a BSM message? I am using this configuration of veins: https://github.com/josephkamel/veins-f2md.

Answer (score 0):

When a vehicle receives a BSM, you can read the position of the current vehicle by using the mobility module:

```
mobility->getPositionAt(simTime()).x
mobility->getPositionAt(simTime()).y
mobility->getPositionAt(simTime()).z
```

It makes little sense to encode the receiver position in the message itself -- you are sending a broadcast. Apart from that, there are other reasons against the proposed procedure.

You could furthermore get the position from the `Signal` of a message.

```
signal.getReceiverPoa().pos.getPositionAt(simTime()).x
signal.getReceiverPoa().pos.getPositionAt(simTime()).y
signal.getReceiverPoa().pos.getPositionAt(simTime()).z
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. How can I actually access the mobility module? Furthermore, is it as simple as augmenting the BasicSafetyMessage.msg file with the necessary fields (i.e., RecvPosx, RecvPosy, etc.) or adding Signal object in the .msg file?

Comment: The C++ code of the `DemoBaseApplLayer` contains examples that answer your question.

Comment: I see, but how may I actually access that mobility object when I wish to log the receiver position in another file. Do I need to just instantiate the DemoBaseApplLayer?